# How to Serialize objects of same type within an object?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, serialization

I want to structure/convert the the following JSON snippet into Kotlin data class such that I can use that in further representation. Sort of expecting list of players and each object to be a player, right now I'm finding it difficult to serialize such cases of same type.

```
"Players": {
        "63084": {
          "Position": "1",
          "Name_Full": "Imam-ul-Haq",
          "Batting": {
            "Style": "LHB",
            "Average": "60.66",
            "Strikerate": "81.54",
            "Runs": "910"
          },
          "Bowling": {
            "Style": "LB",
            "Average": "0",
            "Economyrate": "0",
            "Wickets": "0"
          }
        },
        "57492": {
          "Position": "2",
          "Name_Full": "Fakhar Zaman",
          "Batting": {
            "Style": "LHB",
            "Average": "55.25",
            "Strikerate": "96.64",
            "Runs": "1326"
          },
          "Bowling": {
            "Style": "SLO",
            "Average": "88",
            "Economyrate": "4.75",
            "Wickets": "1"
          }
        },
        "59429": {
          "Position": "3",
          "Name_Full": "Babar Azam",
          "Batting": {
            "Style": "RHB",
            "Average": "50.6",
            "Strikerate": "84.4",
            "Runs": "2328"
          },
          "Bowling": {
            "Style": "OB",
            "Average": "0",
            "Economyrate": "0",
            "Wickets": "0"
          }
        }
}
```

Could do something like this:

```
 @SerializedName("63084")
  val player: Player
```

Doesn't even feel efficient repeating for each ids, even the ids would be dynamic and different for each player. Surely missing something important over here.

API: https://cricket.yahoo.net/sifeeds/cricket/live/json/sapk01222019186652.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API you are consuming is a bit out of standard but you can map Players field to a Map<String, Player> like:

```
data class Player(
    @SerializedName("Position")
    val position: String,
    @SerializedName("Name_Full")
    val name: String 
...)
```

And then:

```
@SerializedName("Players")
val player: Map<String, Player>
```